# Rの日時データ編集について

Tags: r

Rを使っています。
日時データが`"7/9/2016 10:01:58"`や`"12/19/2015 9:57:45"`という形になっていますが、月や日が1桁だったり2桁だったりで非常に扱いにくいです。`substr()`で年月日まで切り出したいのですが文字数が変化しうまく行きません。`"2016/07/09"`や`"2015/12/19"`のような形にしたいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。
`"7"`→`"07"`や`"9"`→`"09"`とできれば`%m`や`%d`を使って組み替えられそうな気がしていますが、1桁→２桁が思いつかないです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`data$date`というカラムに入っているのですがその場合どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。"7/9/2016 10:01:58"を変えるというのは試しましたが全てNAになってしまいました。

Comment: それだと全てのデータがNAになりますね…ちなみに一番最初の個別データのものはそのままで通りました。

Comment: characterでした。as.Dateを使って同じ操作をしましたがやはりNAになりました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。遅いので明日より詳しく検討してみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lubridateパッケージを使うといい感じに処理してくれます。

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

lubridate::mdy_hms("7/9/2016 10:01:58", tz="Japan")
[1] "2016-07-09 10:01:58 JST"

lubridate::mdy_hms("12/19/2015 9:57:45", tz="Japan")
[1] "2015-12-19 09:57:45 JST"
```

Comment: このパッケージは知りませんでした。
`substr`で切り出すために`as.character`が必要でしたがスムーズに行きました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`base` Rでもできます。POSIXctというクラス使おう：

```
format(as.POSIXct("7/9/2016 10:01:58", tz = "Japan", format = "%m/%d/%Y %T"),
       "%Y/%m/%d")
# [1] "2016/07/09"
format(as.POSIXct("12/19/2015 9:57:45", tz = "Japan", format = "%m/%d/%Y %T"),
       "%Y/%m/%d")
# [1] "2015/12/19"
```

詳しくは`?POSIXct`, `?strptime`へ。